# Swift 2.0: Could not find overload. Need Explanation

Tags: xcode, swift, nsurl, xcode7, swift2

I have the following code in my program.

```
    var detailItem: RSSItem? {
    didSet {
        self.configureView()
    }
}

func configureView() {

    if let item: RSSItem = self.detailItem
    {
        if let webView = self.itemWebView
        {

            if let templateURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("template", ofType: "html")!)?
            {
                if var template = NSString(contentsOfURL: templateURL, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)?
                {
                    if let title = item.title
                    {
                        template = template.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("###TITLE###", withString: title)
                    }

                    if let content = item.content
                    {
                        template = template.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("###CONTENT###", withString: content)
                    }
                    else if let description = item.itemDescription
                    {
                        template = template.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("###CONTENT###", withString: description)
                    }

                    if let date = item.pubDate
                    {
                        var formatter = NSDateFormatter()
                        formatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy"

                        template = template.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("###DATE###", withString: formatter.stringFromDate(date))
                    }

                    if let author = item.author
                    {
                        template = template.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("###AUTHOR###", withString: author)
                    }

                    webView.loadHTMLString(template, baseURL: nil)
                }

            }
            else
            {
                if let content = item.content
                {
                    webView.loadHTMLString(content, baseURL: nil)
                }
                else if let description = item.itemDescription
                {
                    webView.loadHTMLString(description, baseURL: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On the line:

```
if let templateURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("template", ofType: "html")!)?
```

I get the following error:
-Could not find an overload for 'pathForResource' that accepts the supplied arguments

Can someone explain this error to me and maybe suggest a solution. I have been reading through various searches on Google but can't quite seem to get what I need.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`NSURL(fileURLWithPath:)` is now return a `NSURL` so just don't use `if let` here.

```
@available(iOS 2.0, *)
init(fileURLWithPath path: String, isDirectory isDir: Bool)
init(fileURLWithPath path: String) // Better to use initFileURLWithPath:isDirectory: if you know if the path is a directory vs non-directory, as it saves an i/o.


@available(iOS 2.0, *)
class func fileURLWithPath(path: String, isDirectory isDir: Bool) -> NSURL
class func fileURLWithPath(path: String) -> NSURL // Better to use fileURLWithPath:isDirectory: if you know if the path is a directory vs non-directory, as it saves an i/o.
```

---

for the line: `if var template = NSString(contentsOfURL: templateURL, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)?`

Its decleration is:

```
convenience init(contentsOfURL url: NSURL, encoding enc: UInt) throws
convenience init(contentsOfFile path: String, encoding enc: UInt) throws
```

So it not returns optional `NSString` either, so you cannot use `if let` again. You have to use `do-try-catch` here.

Apple's document about this:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH42-ID508

Also, you should use multiple unwrapping optional:

`if let x = OptionalX, y = OptionalY { ... }`

Your code is a `pyramid of doom` :)

Comment: This is helpful but how do I implement that into my code? also this didn't help me understand what "overload" means

Comment: `let templateURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("template", ofType: "html")!)` and remove your `else` block. I don't understand what "overload" means, either. Swift doesn't give us much details about that.

Comment: I see thank you for your help let me implement this.

Comment: I am afraid this does not work, I get the following error after the line beginning let templateURL -  Function produces expected type 'Bool'; did you mean to call it with '()'?

Comment: the same error happens with this line of code: `if var template = NSString(contentsOfURL: templateURL, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)?`. I'll update its decleration in my answer.